# How to calculate VaR given mean and sd?

Tags: finance-mathematics, risk-management, value-at-risk, statistical-finance

Sarah manages a hedge fund with a portfolio valued at \$2,000,000. The portfolio's daily returns have a standard deviation of \$3,000 and an average daily return of \$1,200. Calculate the five-day VAR at a 99% confidence level for Sarah's portfolio.

Comment: I tried ChatGPT, and it almost got it right, save for an arithmetic error. Perhaps it could give a head start for you, too.

Comment: just tried it, the formula used is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple. The formula is just:

$VaR_{\alpha,T} = -\mu T + Z_{\alpha} \sigma \sqrt{T}$

Take note the time horizons should match between the drift and the vol terms. Also VaR is usually represented positively despite being a loss. Therefore, the PnL distribution is "reversed".

Comment: The Z represents the one-sided normal deviate.

Comment: I'm actually not sure whether we're allowed to include the positive μ here. If Sarah has done better than risk-free returns hisorically, may we assume that her lucky streak will continue? Also, If the "daily standard deviation" σ is annualized, then do we need to divide by the number of trading days per year somewhere?

Comment: Hi @DimitriVulis, I think OP is just asking a FRM question, so it depends if the question is asking for relative (in which case you are right) or absolute VaR. The lucky streak continuation part goes more into returns forecast and I think the question doesn't go that deep into what is best used as an expected return estimate. On the standard deviation the answer should be to just compute VaR first and then lengthen the horizon *5^0.5. But if the standard deviation is annualized then we should divide by the root of trading days, not by the number of days if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you're right about 1/the number of trading days per year being inside the square root. Just thinking out loud further, in a historical VaR, if one has historically flipped a coin 250 times and got tails, say, 240 times, then there's no choice but to assume that this streak will continue. But in parametric VaR, forcefully assuming that all returns are normal or lognormal, and using their historical volatilities (and correlations), I'm genuinely not sure whether using also historical non-zero mean returns or excess returns complies with the spirit of Basel II.

Comment: @Kai Thanks for the answer! I just had another doubt. The answer comes out be 10356.6 as per the equation. (-1200*5+3000*2.33*2.34). However, usually in excel we use the NORM.INV function to determine the min probability of the mean return and at 99% confidence, it's -0.002889522. Now the daily VaR is -5779.043622 and after multiplying it with the square root of 5 days, the answer is different than 10356 var. Any idea on this?

Comment: @AnkitaDatta, I suggest you use NORM.S.INV for the Z. Also, if you lengthened the horizon at the mean and vol level, there is no need to lengthen it again at the VaR level.

Comment: @kai thanks, actually in my FRA book it's written just multiply the daily VaR with the square root of number of days. but if mean isn't zero, we cannot just multiply it with the square root?

Comment: @AnkitaDatta, if you want to follow your book, you should compute the VaR first (with the mean and vol, and without the Ts') and then lengthen the VaR by multiplying with root of number of days.

Comment: @kai, but the answer is different in both cases:(

Comment: Ah... I see. Right, if that is the case, you should use my formula if the mean is involved, which is the absolute VaR. You should only apply the root of number of days if there is zero mean i.e. you are right in your first statement.

Comment: @kai, one last thing, we do have to subtract the drift component from the vol one right? it's not -V(u*t+sd*z*sqrt(t))

Comment: Yes you subtract the drift from the vol, because a positive drift makes the losses "smaller".

Comment: @AnkitaDatta, feel tick my answer (right below the downvote arrow) if you feel it helped you resolve your query, cheers!

Comment: @Kai Actually, I am unsure about it. Should we be adjusting for mean and make losses smaller? because VaR is the maximum potential loss.

Comment: The drift is always expected to occur in this case, and it also depends if your question asks for absolute or relative VaR. The first requires the drift, the second does not.